# How to generalize my code

Tags: c, bitmap, bit-manipulation

I am working on some bitmap fonts. The idea here is that I am given two files (input.txt and font.txt). I have to read a string from input.txt and transform it using the contents of font.txt and then print the corresponding output to another file called output.txt. Each character in font.txt is represented by a grid of 16x8.

I just implement a simple [rogram to transform a single Char A using to bitmap as below. Can someone please help me to reduce the code.
Thank You.

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int arr[]=
                       {
                        0x00,0x00,0x10,0x38,
                        0x6c,0xc6,0xc6,0xfe,
                        0xc6,0xc6,0xc6,0xc6,
                        0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00
                        };

  int i,k,j;
  int bin[8];
  int c=7;
  for(i=0;i<16;++i)
  {

        bin[0]=arr[i]>>7;
        bin[1]=(arr[i]>>6)&1;
        bin[2]=(arr[i]>>5)&1;
        bin[3]=(arr[i]>>4)&1;
        bin[4]=(arr[i]>>3)&1;
        bin[5]=(arr[i]>>2)&1;
        bin[6]=(arr[i]>>1)&1;
        bin[7]=arr[i]&1;
      k=0;  
      for(j=0;j<4;j++){
      if(bin[k]==0 && bin[k+1]==0)
          {
            printf("..");
          }
          else if(bin[k]==0 && bin[k+1]==0)
          {
            printf(".C");
          }
          else if(bin[k]==0 && bin[k+1]==0)
          {
            printf("C.");

          }
          else
          {
            printf("AA");
      }
k=k+2;      
      }
   printf("\n");

  }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
........
........  
..AA....  
..AAAA..  
AAAAAA..  
AA..AAAA  
AA..AAAA  
AAAAAAAA  
AA..AAAA  
AA..AAAA  
AA..AAAA  
AA..AAAA  
........  
........  
........  
........
```

Comment: The lines starting with "bin[0]=arr[i]>>7;" can be refactored to a for loop...

Comment: Your logic seems wrong since there are 3 cases of `if(bin[k]==0 && bin[k+1]==0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces the same output that you have, but I am ignoring the logic for ".C" and "C." since your codes does as well. ;-)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    unsigned int arr[]=
                       {
                        0x00,0x00,0x10,0x38,
                        0x6c,0xc6,0xc6,0xfe,
                        0xc6,0xc6,0xc6,0xc6,
                        0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00
                        };

  int i,j;
  for(i=0;i<16;++i) {
    unsigned char letter = arr[i];
    for(j =0; j < 7; j++) {
        const char *str = "..";
        if(letter & 0x80) str = "AA";
        fputs(str,stdout);
        letter <<= 1;
    }
    putchar('\n');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
 int main()
    {
        unsigned int arr[]=
                           {
                            0x00,0x00,0x10,0x38,
                            0x6c,0xc6,0xc6,0xfe,
                            0xc6,0xc6,0xc6,0xc6,
                            0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00
                            };

      int i,k,j;
      int bin[8];
      for(i=0;i<16;++i)
      {
          for(j=0;j<8;j++)
          {
            bin[j]=arr[j]>>(7-i2);
          }
          for(k=0;k<8;k+=2){
              if(bin[k]==0 && bin[k+1]==0)
              {
                printf("..");
                continue;
              }
              printf("AA");   
          }
         printf("\n");
      }
    }
```

I deleted printf(".C") and printf("C.") because they never called